# File overflowing into allocated memory C

Tags: c, string, io, malloc

I am trying to write a basic mutant testing script in C, but I've come across some errors which I cannot seem to solve. The first thing to comment is that in the function that seems to be having problems, *namr*, I try am trying to name the file I am creating using a simple caesar cypher to avoid having unwanted characters in the file name. When I run it as is, it seems as though the strings *cexp* and *mcexp* are sometimes getting content from a file I am reading in another function *switchr*.
When I add the printf at Annotation 1 it seems to run fine but the filenames come out wrong. Still, if I comment Annotation 1 out, there is a *malloc(): corrupted top size* error. I have tried various prints to see what is wrong. By the time it gets to Annotation 2, *cexp* and *mcexp* are still the desired length and content but, by the time they get to Annotation 3, they're 26 or 25 characters long and include the starting lines of the file I am reading in other parts of the script.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *namr(char *exp, char *mexp, int ignv) {
    int explen = strlen(exp);
    int mexplen = strlen(mexp);
    //printf("EXPLEN: %d MEXPLEN: %d\n",explen,mexplen);                           
    //ANNOTATION 1
    char *cexp = (char *)malloc(explen + 1);
    char *cmexp = (char *)malloc(mexplen + 1); //Exp in Caeser Cipher
    for (int i = 0; i < explen; i++) {
       cexp[i]= (exp[i] ? 'A' + exp[i] % 25 : exp[i]);
       printf("%d - %c - %c\n", i, exp[i], 'A' + exp[i] % 25);                            
    //ANNOTATION 2
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mexplen; i++) {
       cmexp[i]= (mexp[i] ? 'A' + mexp[i] % 25 : mexp[i]);
    }
    printf("EXP: %s\nMEXP: %s\n", exp, mexp);
    printf("CEXP: %s\nCMEXP: %s\n", cexp, cmexp);                                    
    //ANNOTATION 3
    printf("%s - %d\n%s - %d\n%d\n", cexp, strlen(cexp),
           cmexp, strlen(cmexp), strlen("./U_SWITCH_MTNTS/TO%03.c"));
    char *outname = (char *)malloc((30 + explen + mexplen));
    sprintf(outname, "./U_SWITCH_MTNTS/%sTO%s%03d.c", cexp, cmexp, ignv);
    free(cexp);
    free(cmexp);
    return outname;
}

int countr(char *filename, char *exp) {
    int out = 0;
    int i, flag;
    int inlen = strlen(exp);
    char c;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");                        
    while (c != EOF) {
        for (i = 0, flag = 0; i < inlen; i++) {
            if (exp[i] != c) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            } 
            c = getc(f);
        }
        if (flag == 0)
            out++;
        c = getc(f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return out;
}

char *switchr(char *filename, char *exp, char *mexp, int ignv) {
    int i, flag,buffcount;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    char *outname = namr(exp, mexp, ignv);
    FILE *fout = fopen(outname, "w");                       
    char c = getc(f);
    int ignc = ignv;
    int inlen = strlen(exp);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(inlen * sizeof(char));
    while (c != EOF) {
        for (i = 0, flag = 0, buffcount = 0; i < inlen; i++) {
            if (exp[i] != c) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                buffer[buffcount] = c;
                buffcount++;
                c = getc(f);
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            if(ignc == 0) {
                fputs(mexp, fout);
            } else {
                for (i = 0; i < buffcount; i++)
                    fputc(buffer[i], fout); 
            }
            ignc--;
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < buffcount; i++)
                fputc(buffer[i], fout);   
        }
        fputc(c, fout);
        c = getc(f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(fout);
    return outname;
}

void mstrswitch(char *filename) {
    int ecount = countr(filename, "==");
    char **filenames = (char **)malloc(5 * ecount * sizeof(char *));
    char command[100];
    system("mkdir U_SWITCH_MTNTS");
    system("mkdir TEST_OBJECTS");
    for (int i = 0;i < ecount; i++) {
        filenames[5 * i]     = switchr("test.c", "==", "<=", i);
        filenames[5 * i + 1] = switchr("test.c", "==", ">=", i);
        filenames[5 * i + 2] = switchr("test.c", "==", ">", i);
        filenames[5 * i + 3] = switchr("test.c", "==", "<", i);
        filenames[5 * i + 4] = switchr("test.c", "==", "!=", i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 * ecount; i++) {
        sprintf(command, "gcc -o ./TEST_OBJECTS/test%03d %s", i, filenames[i]);
        system(command);
        sprintf(command, "./TEST_OBJECTS/test%03d", i);
        system(command);
        free(filenames[i]);
    }
    free(filenames);
}

int main() {
    mstrswitch("test.c");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: `sizeof(char *)*5*ecount` has an advantage over `5*ecount*sizeof(char *)`: less likely to overflow.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Que?  How does reordering the terms in the expression alter the possibility of overflow?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `(size_t)*(int)*(int)` performs 2 `size_t * size_t` multiplications. `(int)*(int)*(size_t)` performs 1 `int*int` and 1 `size_t * size_t` multiplication.  As `size_t` overwhelmingly has wider positive range than `int`, less chance for overflow.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: OK — I see where you're coming from.  I'm not convinced the compiler can't rearrange the sequence of operations, but what you suggest might head off trouble.

Comment: Compiler cannot re-order as that is functionally different. Consider if `ecount < 0`, complaier cannot assume it is positive.

Comment: UB can lead to any result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232921/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1):

You never zero terminates the strings `cexp` and `cmexp`. So add these two lines:

```
for(int i=0;i<explen;i++)
{
   cexp[i]= (exp[i]?'A'+exp[i]%25: exp[i]);
   printf("%d - %c - %c\n",i,exp[i],'A'+exp[i]%25);
}
cexp[explen]= '\0';   <------------------- add
for(int i=0;i<mexplen;i++)
{
   cmexp[i]= (mexp[i]?'A'+mexp[i]%25: mexp[i]);
}
cmexp[mexplen]= '\0';   <------------------- add
```

Besides that the following line looks strange:

```
cexp[i]= (exp[i]?'A'+exp[i]%25: exp[i]);
          ^^^^^^
          Always true
```

Having a condition that always returns true is probably not what you intended.